# Events emptied from bin on web gui become permanant in API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have been creating events in the API with eventIDs based on another calendar system. I can read/write the calendar no worries, but I have managed to create events that can no longer be modified/deleted.

After creating the events in the API using python, I went into the google calendar web gui, and deleted them. I then went into the bin and emptied it.

The event can still be retrieved with a get command, and it's status is 'cancelled'. If I attempt to delete it I am greeted by a 403, forbidden error. I get the same if I attempt to update it.

I can update/delete events that haven't gone through the process of being emptied from the bin. I would like to re-use the eventIds, so if anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar Events that are deleted, **disregarding whether via UI or via API** (using [Events.delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)), don't just "disappear" immediately. They just **change their status from `confirmed` to `cancelled`**.

As you can see in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations):

> Such cancelled events will eventually disappear, so do not rely on them being available indefinitely.

But for the time being, the resource will still exist, or at least the `id` you want to reuse, since:

> Deleted events are only guaranteed to have the **id** field populated.

Because of all this, **you cannot immediately reuse the `eventId` from an event that you just deleted**. Using [Events.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) or [Events.update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) won't be useful either, since the `id` of an existing event cannot be modified.

I don't see the usefulness of reusing an `eventId`, though. Are you aware that it's not necessary to specify an `eventId` while creating it, right? If you don't specify it, an `id` will be automatically generated by the server.

#### Reference:

- [Calendar API: Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)

Comment: I was hoping to use the same ids as my internal rostering system. I guess I'll have to use an extended property instead. It would have been nice to have these in step.

It's very strange that the event still persists, and only becomes locked once it's emptied from the bin though, seems like a security hole. It gives the user the false beleif that the data is gone.